# How to get unique documents in elastic search based on a field, and 'group by' the result based on other fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have just begun with elastic search and need to solve a problem too complex for me. I have thousands of documents in the index from which I have to query a predefined number of documents (which can be a few thousand too), I have to find groups of documents based on some fields, out of the unique documents based on another field (number of unique documents can be up to a few hundred).

A document in my Index looks like this:

```
{  
 "complexProperty1" : {
            "A" : "example",
            "B" : "1",
            "D" : true,
            "E" : "case",
            "F" : ["guide1","guide2"]
},
   "complexProperty2" : {
            "X" : "10",
            "Y" : ["specimen1","specimen2"],
            "Z" : "blueprint"
}
}
```

Many documents will have `complexProperty1.A` as **"example"**. I want to include them once and the resulting documents need to be grouped by `complexProperty1.D` and `complexProperty1.E`, i.e. for each pair of `complexProperty1.D` and `complexProperty1.E`, I have a list of documents (I only need these documents in my result). I am using Nest to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can start off w/ a bunch of raw [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) aggregations and build your way back to the [NEST DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-aggregation-usage.html):

```
POST complexities/_doc
{
  "complexProperty1": {
    "A": "example",
    "B": "1",
    "D": true,
    "E": "case",
    "F": [
      "guide1",
      "guide2"
    ]
  },
  "complexProperty2": {
    "X": "10",
    "Y": [
      "specimen1",
      "specimen2"
    ],
    "Z": "blueprint"
  }
}
```

```
GET complexities/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_A": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "complexProperty1.A.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_D": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "complexProperty1.D"
          }
        },
        "by_E": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "complexProperty1.E.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In order to get the underlying docs you can append a `top_hits` agg to each sub-agg, incl. the top-level one:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_A": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "complexProperty1.A.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits_only": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": "*"
          }
        },
        "by_D": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "complexProperty1.D"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_hits_only": {
              "top_hits": {
                "_source": "*"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "by_E": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "complexProperty1.E.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_hits_only": {
              "top_hits": {
                "_source": "*"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciated! Btw, I need to group `by_D` and `by_E`, all the unique documents that I got by `by_A`. I don't need the documents inside all the aggregations. Also, I have a predefined size of documents on which I need to apply this, can I set that size instead of 0?

Comment: Can you update your question with the response you're looking for?